# how to use code-push functionality in an Ionic Capacitor project?

Tags: ionic-framework, native, capacitor, code-push, ionic-react

I Need to update my Ionic Capacitor app(React).I tried the code-push with Cordova Plugin. But not working for me. Anyone know about the code-push technology with capacitor plugin? or How can we use the Cordova code-push in a capacitor app?. Please reply.